# export files from salesforce?

Tags: data-export

we have an excel file that you previously exported from Salesforce.  What feature of Salesforce did you use to create the file? The Excel file includes 2000 Opportunity records representing 800 different Accounts.  Describe the steps you would use in Excel to create a list of the unique Account records along the exact number of Opportunities corresponding to each.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't export any file ;)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113375 for a quick start on Reporting, or https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/reports_dashboards for the trailhead. Reports allow you to export to csv/excel

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Report Tab in salesforce to get data exported from different custom and standard Objects includes opportunities, accounts etc. There will be standard reports already available that might be having your requested details which have Account & Opportunities and you can do "summarise report format" on account level to get all opportunities under an Account. Once you get the required output you can export in excel or any format as you wish..

Refer below so that you will get a better understanding

As mentioned by Folkert above Trailheads will be the perfect way to start

Also please check Salesforce video -  [click here](https://youtu.be/0CMX96wMrWs)